# Google usually return 403 and 500 error when uploading file to Google Drive

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using Google drive stored files and i created a application for clients can upload to it.But sometimes google drive return 403 and 500 error although before my application work fine(upload and set permission file successfully).I don't understand my application have bug or google drive server doesn't work fine??
  I'm using C# for my application

Answer (score 0):

Hey may [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs) helps you. Without any code I can not help you more.

**403 Forbidden:**

> The request was a valid request, but the server is refusing to respond to it.[2] Unlike a 401 Unauthorized response, authenticating will make no difference.[2] On servers where authentication is required, this commonly means that the provided credentials were successfully authenticated but that the credentials still do not grant the client permission to access the resource (e.g., a recognized user attempting to access restricted content).

**500 Internal Server Error:**

> A generic error message, given when no more specific message is suitable